# List of subdirectories that contains a particular file name

Tags: bash, shell, files, find

I am wondering if i can do this in a single shell command.

I am in home directory and want to find a list of subdirectories that contains a particular file. The file name and the depth is always same. For example if something like this,

```
/karthik/A/B/C/1/D/E.txt
/karthik/A/B/C/2/D/E.txt
/karthik/A/B/C/3/D/E.txt
/karthik/A/B/C/4/D/E.txt
/karthik/A/B/C/5/D/E.txt
```

I want to print 1 2 3 4 5

Can we do it in a single shell command and if so, how?

Comment: `find . -name E.txt` ?

Answer (score 1):

Using find and awk

```
find . -mindepth 7 -name E.txt | awk -F/ '$0=$6'
```

Answer (score 0):

awk as well :

```
find . -type f -name 'E.txt' | awk -F/ '$0=$5'
```

Please check the capture @ https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDiiA.jpg for the folder layout

Comment: Is it possible if I can include path next to name field? I mean -name 'D/E.txt'

Comment: If you try, this will come up: **UNIX filenames usually don't contain slashes (though pathnames do). That means that '-name ‘c/E.txt’' will probably evaluate to false all the time on this system.**